# Chrome Extensions and Firefox WebExtensions Manifest: Application Key Support

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, firefox-addon-webextensions

Firefox [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) require the [applications key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications) in extension's manifests.

Chrome's [extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) do not appear to support the applications key and Chrome throws an error when the key is present, unlike Firefox which simply ignores unsupported keys.

Is there a way around this error that does not require the use of two different manifests for each browser?

Chrome gives this error when the applications key appears in the manifest:

`Unrecognized manifest key 'applications'.`

Comment: Just have 2 manifests or create those dynamically depending on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not directly answer the question, but according to a blog from Microsoft [Microsoft Edge extensions now available to preview](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/03/17/preview-extensions/),

> In keeping with our commitment to an interoperable web, we’re participating in the W3C Browser Extension Community Group’s efforts to **define standardized extension APIs based on familiar web technologies**.

So maybe we can look forward to the future.